# flutter Single directional zoom function

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Fgr.gif)
Pardon my English, but I wanted to achieve an effect similar to the GIF I posted, and I found that onScaleUpdate provides a ScaleUpdateDetails property, I also see horizontalScale and verticalScale with two different axes.
I thought I could easily use either horizontalScale or verticalScale to achieve my goal, but as I used it, the value of horizontalScale changed even if I just scaled vertically.
So I don't know how to do that, only one direction is going to scale.
By the way, is localFocalPoint the midpoint of the line between the two touchpoints? If so, how can I get the coordinates of any of the touch points

Thanks for answering my questions.

I tried to simply use horizontalScale and verticalScale, but it didn't work, because gestures can't accurately scale horizontally or vertically, so the single direction scaling horizontalScale and verticalScale will change.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  double _containerWidth = 200.0;
  double _containerHeight = 200.0;
  double _baseWidth = 100.0;
  double _baseHeight = 100.0;

  void _updateContainerSize(double horizontalScale, double verticalScale) {
    setState(() {
      _containerWidth = _baseWidth * horizontalScale;
      
      _containerHeight = _baseHeight * verticalScale;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Pinch to Shrink Container'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: _containerWidth,
                height: _containerHeight,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
                if(details.pointerCount == 2){
                  _updateContainerSize(
                    details.horizontalScale,
                    details.verticalScale,
                  );
                }

              },
              onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) {
                _baseWidth = _containerWidth;
                _baseHeight = _containerHeight;
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 218, 218),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                height: 200,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried to judge the direction by calculating horizontalScale and verticalScale's scaling difference and absolute value comparison. The result was still that the data was wrong due to inaccurate gestures.

```
                      if(hS == 0){
                        hS = detail.horizontalScale;
                      }
                      if(vS == 0){
                        vS = detail.verticalScale;
                      }
                      if((detail.horizontalScale - hS).abs() > (detail.verticalScale - vS).abs()){
                        debugPrint("horizontal"); // horizontal
                      }else{
                        debugPrint("vertical"); // vertical
                      }
```